# How to enable Intel Virtualization technology

Tags: android, haxm

I'm beginning to develop android apps, I recently heard about HAXM so I downloaded it unpacked it and started installing, however I got the fallowing error "This computer meets requirements for HAXM, but VT-x is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled".
I looked at a number of threads connected with this problem and the majority say to enable Intel Virtualization technology. I'm having trouble navigating to the CPU configuration in the BIOS to do this using windows 10.

Comment: Contact your desktop or notebook manufacturer. We have no means of helping you, since we do not have your Windows 10 machine, or even know what that machine is.

Comment: at the time of boot press F12(mostly if you have windows) and go to boot section menu and enable VT-X.